# How to say more elegantly "to move the index in a disapproving manner"?

Tags: word-request, idiom-request

I am talking about the specific gesture of waving an index to show disapproval to a kid, often accompanied with the sound "tss". Is there a word or an idiom for that?

Comment: I think you mean "index **finger**".  We don't usually just call it an "index" by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gesture is called **wagging your finger** at someone. [Cambridge defines it as:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/learner-english/wag)

> If you wag your finger, you move it from side to side, often to tell someone not to do something.

Answer (score 1):

The gesture of moving an index **finger** back and forth to express disapproval is usually called 'wagging a finger' or 'finger wagging'.

> If you wag your finger, you shake it repeatedly and quickly from side
> to side, usually because you are annoyed with someone.

[Wag (Collins Dictionary)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wag)

[image]